# How to automatically get reoccurring notifications in flutter after a period of time?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a function `_showNotificationsAfterSecond` to get notifications after a delay of 3 seconds. I tried to make a for loop to run this function 8 times so that I get 8 notifications after a delay of 3 seconds each. Upon pressing the "Start Reminders" button (which calls the function), I only get one notification and after that nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LocalNotifications(),
    );
  }
}

class LocalNotifications extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalNotificationsState createState() => _LocalNotificationsState();
}

class _LocalNotificationsState extends State<LocalNotifications> {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings;
  IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings;
  InitializationSettings initializationSettings;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializing();
  }

  void initializing() async {
    androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
    iosInitializationSettings = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        androidInitializationSettings, iosInitializationSettings);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }


  void _showNotificationsAfterSecond() async {
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++) {

      notificationAfterSec();
    }
  }

  Future<Null> delay(int milliseconds) {
    return new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));
  }

  Future<void> notificationAfterSec() async {
    var timeDelayed = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 3));
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'second  id', 'second heading', 'second  text',
        priority: Priority.High,
        importance: Importance.Max,
        ticker: 'test');

    IOSNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
    NotificationDetails(androidNotificationDetails, iosNotificationDetails);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        1, 'yo', 'wfqawsfqsqacqfqcwefs', timeDelayed, notificationDetails);
  }

  Future<void> turnOffNotification(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }


  Future onSelectNotification(String payLoad) {
    if (payLoad != null) {
      print(payLoad);
    }

    // we can set navigator to navigate another screen
  }

  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(body),
      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              print("");
            },
            child: Text("Okay")),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hydration"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(

            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              DialogUtils.showCustomDialog(context,
                  title: "Why should this be a priority?",
                  okBtnText: "Got It!",
                  okBtnFunction: () => Navigator.pop(context));
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/wat.jfif'), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 30.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Water Intake Reminder',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0)),
                  Container(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/drinking.jpg',
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                      ), //adjust this baad mein
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
              ),
              height: 400.0,
              width: 300.0,
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 20.0, 8.0, 8.0)),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 1.0, 8.0, 1.0)),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),

                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "btn1",
                  onPressed: _showNotificationsAfterSecond,
                  label: Text(
                    "Start Reminders",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0)),
                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "btn2",
                  onPressed: () {
                    turnOffNotification(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
                  },
                  label: Text(
                    "Stop Reminders",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),

              ],
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DialogUtils {
  static DialogUtils _instance = new DialogUtils.internal();

  DialogUtils.internal();

  factory DialogUtils() => _instance;

  static void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context,
      {@required String title,
        String okBtnText = "hhegregrbge",
        @required Function okBtnFunction}) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
            title: Text(
              title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            content: Text(
              " When you're pregnant, you need more water than the average person in order to form amniotic fluid, produce extra blood, build newtissue, carry nutrients, enhance digestion, and flush out wastes and toxins.Since you need more water during pregnancy, how much is enough? It’s recommended that you drink 8-12 glasses of water a day, or 2.3 liters.",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  okBtnText,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: okBtnFunction,
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to use different `id`, you can pass `i` as schedule id 
code snippet

```
void _showNotificationsAfterSecond() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      notificationAfterSec(i);
    }
  }
  
Future<void> notificationAfterSec(int id) async {
  ...
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(id, '${id} yo',
        'wfqawsfqsqacqfqcwefs', timeDelayed, notificationDetails);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LocalNotifications(),
    );
  }
}

class LocalNotifications extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocalNotificationsState createState() => _LocalNotificationsState();
}

class _LocalNotificationsState extends State<LocalNotifications> {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings;
  IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings;
  InitializationSettings initializationSettings;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializing();
  }

  void initializing() async {
    androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('mipmap/ic_launcher');
    iosInitializationSettings = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        androidInitializationSettings, iosInitializationSettings);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }

  void _showNotificationsAfterSecond() async {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      notificationAfterSec(i);
    }
  }

  Future<Null> delay(int milliseconds) {
    return new Future.delayed(new Duration(milliseconds: milliseconds));
  }

  Future<void> notificationAfterSec(int id) async {
    var timeDelayed = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 3));
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'second  id', 'second heading', 'second  text',
            priority: Priority.High,
            importance: Importance.Max,
            ticker: 'test');

    IOSNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(androidNotificationDetails, iosNotificationDetails);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(id, '${id} yo',
        'wfqawsfqsqacqfqcwefs', timeDelayed, notificationDetails);
  }

  Future<void> turnOffNotification(
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payLoad) {
    if (payLoad != null) {
      print(payLoad);
    }

    // we can set navigator to navigate another screen
  }

  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    return CupertinoAlertDialog(
      title: Text(title),
      content: Text(body),
      actions: <Widget>[
        CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              print("");
            },
            child: Text("Okay")),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hydration"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              DialogUtils.showCustomDialog(context,
                  title: "Why should this be a priority?",
                  okBtnText: "Got It!",
                  okBtnFunction: () => Navigator.pop(context));
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.info_outline),
            shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 30.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Water Intake Reminder',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0)),
                  Container(
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                      ), //adjust this baad mein
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
              ),
              height: 400.0,
              width: 300.0,
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 20.0, 8.0, 8.0)),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 1.0, 8.0, 1.0)),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),
                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "btn1",
                  onPressed: _showNotificationsAfterSecond,
                  label: Text(
                    "Start Reminders",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0)),
                FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  heroTag: "btn2",
                  onPressed: () {
                    turnOffNotification(flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin);
                  },
                  label: Text(
                    "Stop Reminders",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0)),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DialogUtils {
  static DialogUtils _instance = new DialogUtils.internal();

  DialogUtils.internal();

  factory DialogUtils() => _instance;

  static void showCustomDialog(BuildContext context,
      {@required String title,
      String okBtnText = "hhegregrbge",
      @required Function okBtnFunction}) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent[100],
            title: Text(
              title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            content: Text(
              " When you're pregnant, you need more water than the average person in order to form amniotic fluid, produce extra blood, build newtissue, carry nutrients, enhance digestion, and flush out wastes and toxins.Since you need more water during pregnancy, how much is enough? It’s recommended that you drink 8-12 glasses of water a day, or 2.3 liters.",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  okBtnText,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: okBtnFunction,
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```